# .change() not working in ie and when changed to .click() same issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue: This code works in firefox chrome and safari but not in IE 8. I had `.change` but i found out that it does not work in ie so i did `.click` and tried it again in all the browsers, all is working, try in ie still not working. The anythingSlider is a jquery library im using and i know for sure thats not the issue (going reverse works like selecting the item on the drop down and moving to that slide works everywhere including ie. Thanks.

My code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#skillslist').click(function()
  {var str = $(this).attr('value');
  var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
  var matches = str.match(pattern);
 var myInteger = parseInt(matches);
 $('#slider').anythingSlider(myInteger);


  });


    });
</script>

 <select name='myList'  id='skillslist'>
 <option>Subscription Days Remaining: <? echo $days ?></option>
 <option id='skill1'>Skill 1: Hand Washing</option>
 <option id='skill2'>Skill 2: Abdominal Thrust on Conscious Resident</option>
 <option id='skill3'>Skill 3: Ambulation using a Gait Belt</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: why `$(document).ready()` twice?

Comment: Don't bind `click` to `<select>` elements, use `change`. Remember that a user can select an option using the keyboard too. So, what's your problem when using `change`?

Comment: sorry about the mistype and ie does not support `.change` or it does not work in ie. This apparently is a known issue.

Comment: No, actually this isn't known. I've been using to bind a `change` event listener on `<select>` elements since... forever, even in IE6 and 7, even if I don't use jQuery. "It does not work" isn't an answer, please explain a little more: it simply just does nothing?

Comment: Yes it does nothing. Also here is why I thought it does not work in ie:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678771/jquery-select-change-click-problem-change-doesnt-work-in-ie-click-doesnt-wo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#skillslist').change(function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    // ...
});
```

I always try to avoid `$(this).attr('value')` or `this.value`, because select box values should be queried using `this.options[this.selectedIndex]` ... which is what `.val()` does for you.

Before you say "it does not work" describe what's not working first and make sure to eliminate other factors by `alert()`ing the `myInteger` value.

Comment: Sorry by not working i meant does nothing, as if it was not even there. Also that works, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('#skillslist').on('change', function(){  // change instead of click
  var str = this.value;
  var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
  var matches = str.match(pattern);
  var myInteger = parseInt(matches);
  $('#slider').anythingSlider(myInteger);


  });
});
```

Not sure, if you select append to dom after page load then you should go for

```
$('body').on('change', '#skillslist', function(){  // change instead of click
  var str = this.value;
  var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
  var matches = str.match(pattern);
  var myInteger = parseInt(matches);
  $('#slider').anythingSlider(myInteger);


  });
});
```

**NOTE** `body` can be replace with the container of the select box.

Comment: .change does not work in ie which is why i tried .click but im still having an issue with it (still not working).

Comment: @user860869 does your item append to dom after page load?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But I use `.click` else where and do other things with the id and it all works.